# Hi, I am using ASP.NET and Javascript timer, How can I prevent my timer reset on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Below is the Js code, How can i use asp.net session and pass timer value (300) from code behind.

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {

    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;

    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft/60) + ":"+ timeleft%60);

    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

progress(300, 300, $('#progressBar'));
//value passing here in seconds.
//Is there any way to use session to store value and check in page load
```

Comment: You can try getting and saving timeLeft in localstorage but that is shared between tabs/windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sessionStorage` to save variables across a session (in a single tab). For example:

```
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  sessionStorage.timer = JSON.stringify({ timeleft, timetotal });
  var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
  $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft/60) + ":"+ timeleft%60);
  if(timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
if (sessionStorage.timer) {
  const { timeleft, timetotal } = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.timer);
  if (timeleft > 0) progress(timeleft, timetotal, $('#progressBar'));
  else progress(300, 300, $('#progressBar'));
} else progress(300, 300, $('#progressBar'));
```

Note that this implementation automatically starts `progress` anew on page load if nothing exists in `sessionStorage` *or* if `timeleft` is 0.